# How to IPv4 through IPv6?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv6, nat, isp

My ISP (Unitymedia Germany) tunnels IPv4 traffic through slow and unstable CGNAT (they call it "AFTR", which seems to be a similar thing) but comes with reliable and native IPv6.

Now, is there any way I can take full advantage of the IPv6 connection and access IPv4 hosts through the native IPv6 connection from my Win7 PC?

Naturally, I have searched Google, but any hits are about accessing IPv6 through IPv4, which is the opposite of what I want to do. I've also come across buzzwords like *NAT64* and *DNS64*, but couldn't find much information about it for end users.

<sub>If it helps, I have a linux server with IPv6 in a datacenter near me, which could be abused for any potential shenanigans.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://nat64.tuxis.nl. They provide a free NAT64+DNS64 service that makes your machine think that the whole world turned off IPv4 and migrated to IPv6. Your machine can then be IPv6-only and their NAT64 gateway will NAT your IPv6 traffic towards the real IPv4 hosts.

Comment: This sounds like it works sort of in the same way as what my ISP is giving me. Will it be more reliable and yield better performance although it's a more public service?

Comment: Probably not, unless your ISP's AFTR is really bad. Your ISP is giving you DS-Lite. You still have IPv4, but it is transported over IPv6 to your ISP's AFTR and NAT'ed there. With DNS64 you don't use IPv4 yourself at all anymore but pretend that the whole world is IPv6 and the NAT64 service provides access to the IPv4 internet. Either way there is NAT involved, the difference is in the details, and your ISP's equipment is closer to you than some service based in The Netherlands...

Answer (score 0):

For web browsing you could use some http proxy which is available via IPv6. 
If you find SOCKS proxy, you can also use it for other services, and not
just web browsing. Third alternative is to pay for some VPN which is
available on IPv6, and tunnel your IPv4 traffic through that.

Or, longer term, you could promote IPv6 (like, bugging owners of services
you have problems with on IPv4 to implement IPv6) and help it become more
available, thus eliminating your problems.